# Selecting quantity of most recent values using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I saw some solutions for this in MySQL, but can't seem to find anything for SQLite.  I am trying to get values for the 7 most recent entries in my database.  I know how to order them by date, but for some reason I can't find the syntax for returning a given number of them.
This is the query, using JDBC

```
PreparedStatement get_recent_id = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM workout_log ORDER BY t desc");
```

This will return them ordered, but I was thinking `SELECT 7 *`....would work, but this is the error I get
`Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "FROM": syntax error)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:42)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:404)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:399)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:383)
    at WeeklyReport.main(WeeklyReport.java:38)`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM workout_log ORDER BY t desc Limit 7;
```

Also note that using `*` can lead to some problems down stream. What if your columns change order or you add new one? Think of listing your fields.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be helpful. Use `limit`

```
SELECT * FROM workout_log ORDER BY t desc limit 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Add only `limit 0,7`

The query is :-

```
SELECT * FROM workout_log ORDER BY t desc limit 0,7;
```